# Piecewise functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I have only recently began working with MATLAB for Uni this year, and as a homework quiz question I was asked to create a piecewise function (that I have called "piecewise_method") that is able to enact a different equation on "x" depending on if "x" is below 0, between 0 and 8, or above 8. Here is the code I have written so far.

```
function solution = piecewise_method(x)

% given the value of the input x, the function
% piecewise_method will choose from one of the three specified
% equations to enact upon the given value of x
% and give the user a solution

solution = zeros(size(x));
e = exp(1);

for j = 1:size(x)
    a = x(j);

    if a < 0
        solution(j) = -a.^3 - 2*a.^2 + 3*a;
    elseif (a >= 0) && (a <= 8)
        solution(j) = (12/pi)*sin(pi*a./4);
    else
        solution(j) = ((600.*e.^(a-8))./(7*(14+6.*e.^(a-8))) - 30/7);
    end
end
```

When run with the input...

```
x = -3:12
```

It produces this result for the variable solution...

solution =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now this suggests to me that the array is being properly created, but for one reason or another the for loop isn't running properly, or as expected. I tried reconstructing the for loop a number of times from the basic level up, but when I started putting in the equations it began to fall apart again, so I believe something could be wrong with my equations (which is why I put brackets everywhere, just in case).

The question also asks me to use if statements, so I can't try using other methods to produce the piecewise method function, and from my searching around, there didn't seem to be many examples of if statements in piecewise functions.

If you could provide any suggestions that could help me with this function that would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

P.S. If there are any suggestions you have for improving my questions in the future that would be good too!

Comment: You just need to substitute `for j = 1:size(x)` with `for j = 1:numel(x)`. `size(x)` will return [1 16] for rows and columns of x, whereas `numel(x)` will return the number of elements, irrespectively of x being a row or column vector. More in general, break points are your friends: put a break point within your function and walk it step by step, looking at variable values!

Comment: Oh right, I hadn't seen the option about breakpoints before you mentioned it. MATLAB gives me an error In regards to indexing functions when I try your method, is there perhaps something else that needs to be done first?

Comment: What is the error? Anyway, my method is exactly like the one proposed in the answer below, so if that one works, mine should too...

Comment: I see, I think I had been confused. But it is working now, thank you.

Comment: Don’t do `e.^(a-8)`, it is much more precise (and likely faster) to do `exp(a-8)`. Note it’s the same number of characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `length` instead of `size` at the `for` loop.

The output of `size` function is the dimensions of x, which for your example of `x=-3:12` returns `size(x)=[1 16]`. Then your `for` loop will run for `j=1:size(x)`, i.e `j=1:1`, i.e `j=1`.

The output of `length` is the length of the largest array dimension of `x`, as listed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html). In your example: `length(x) = 16`, then `j=1:length(x)=1:16`.

Or, you could use `size(x,2)`, which will return the size of the 2nd dimension of `x`, same as `length` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Also if you don't mind me asking, is there anyway to improve my questions for future?

Comment: I think your question was clear and well written. Look at the edit made to your question to see how to properly add your code to it so it will be easy to read. And ofcource, as mentioned in the comments, try using breakpoints for debugging and finding the problems yourself - this is the best way to learn. If my answer helped you, please accept it by pressing the 'V' - This supports me and lets other know you have recieved an answer that pleases you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments and [RadioJava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016883/3978545), you need to check your loop. I would use `size(x,2)` (number of columns in `x`) or `numel(x)` (number of elements in `x`).

```
for j = 1:numel(x)
    % ...
```

Others recommend `length(x)` which is `max(size(x))`. I generally try to avoid this because it's not explicit which dimension you want to look along for matrices.

Aside from just repeating info though, I want to show you could do this much more efficiently with logical indexing, and remove the problematic loop entirely...

```
function solution = piecewise_method(x)

% given the value of the input x, the function
% piecewise_method will choose from one of the three specified
% equations to enact upon the given value of x
% and give the user a solution

solution = zeros(size(x));
e = exp(1);

idx = (x<0);
solution(idx) = -x(idx).^3 - 2*x(idx).^2 + 3*x(idx);
idx = (x>=0 & x<=8);
solution(idx) = (12/pi)*sin(pi*x(idx)/4);
idx = (x>8);
solution(idx) = (600*e.^(x(idx)-8))./(7*(14+6*e.^(x(idx)-8))) - 30/7;
```

Note you could easily have conditions and (anonymous) functions in arrays and loop over them to make this much more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and answer. As part of my response though I did need to implement a series of if and elseif statements though or else I would have tried something like what you proposed above. Also so that I can read more about this type of function (the way you are able to use "x(idx)" etc.) what would you call this? Like what should I search up to find out more about using this method in future programs? Thank you for your help.

Comment: As stated in the answer, it's called [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Comment: @Wolfie I wanted to suggest this solution because I thought it would be faster... but after implementing it, it took twice the time of the loop function! Out of curiosity, did you by any chance test it?

Comment: Loops aren't necessarily slow. No I didn't test it, did you only test using the very small example the OP gave? At sub-thousandths of a second runtime I can't imagine any relative benchmarks are reliable...

Comment: No i tried on a 500 elements array...but you are right, maybe thing would change with even larger arrays. Never mind!